# Easy way to map NSTableView column identifiers onto ivars?

Tags: swift, nstableview

I just want to be sure I'm not missing some blindingly simple solution to this...

If you use an Array of Dictionaries for your tableView's datasource, you can easily retrieve any value with something along the lines of...

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> AnyObject? {
    return myData().objectAtIndex(row).objectForKey(tableColumn!.identifier)
}
```

I've implemented my data as an array of `struct` with lots of ivars. So to get the data I have a switch statement with 50 (and growing) lines which is a pain to maintain.

It would be much simpler to have some sort of analog of objectForKey that would map a string onto an ivar and return the value. This is something one would normally do with reflection, but but I don't think Swift has that (yet)?

So does anyone have a good solution here? I see a few mentions around SO, but nothing concrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your class inherits from `NSObject` (and thus participates in the ObjC runtime), you can look up property values using [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) — a form of reflection/introspection not specific to Swift but available to all Cocoa objects.

```
class MyClass: NSObject {
    var foo: String = "text"
    var bar: Int = 3
    var baz = ["zap" : 42]
}

let thing = MyClass()
let a = thing.valueForKey("foo") // "text"
let b = thing.valueForKey("bar") // 3
let c = thing.valueForKeyPath("baz.zap") // 42
```

The `valueForKey(_:)` method looks up properties by name, goes through their accessors, and returns a value wrapped (at runtime) in whatever Cocoa class is appropriate, if any. (For example, the static type of `a` is `Optional<AnyObject>`, and at run time the types you can safely unwrap and cast to are related to `NSString`.)

KVC does lots of cool stuff — some of which Swift has more-type-safe equivalents for (`map` et al) and some of which remains unique. For example, `valueForKeyPath(_:)` takes a dot-separated list of keys that recursively looks up values within values — like the `baz.zap` example above.

Comment: Also, just to be pedantic... in Swift there are no "ivars" anymore. ([Unless you're in Seattle and like chowder.](http://http://www.ivars.com)) *Properties* always have accessors, and their backing storage is managed by Swift.

Comment: Oh my. I was fully aware of this mechanism but never even thought to use it in this case. My objects *do* inherit from NSObject, and this works like a charm! I will *not* forget this for next time!